# Using Regex to find particular set of numbers considering length limitation in python

Tags: python, regex

I am going to find numbers containing `62`, but only those numbers starting with `09` and length 11. e.x.

```
093627
09206277
09129627173
097177627878328218
```

All these numbers have `62` and starting with `09` but only No 3 is the answer because its length is 11. The following solution is not working fully

```
f = re.findall('09[0-9]*62[0-9]*', '093627, 09206277, 09129627173, 097177627878328218')
```

`09[0-9]*62[0-9]` is not complete as it must find only 11 digits numbers.

Comment: Instead of the `*` quantifier you may use for example `{0,2}` to match anything from 0 to 2 repetitions. But I don't know if you can make the length of the second set (after the 62) depend on the length of the fist set. It might be easier to just go with your solution and check the length of the match in a second step.

Comment: @Feodoran agreed if many number are of length 11. If there are many numbers containing 62 but only few of the correct length, it might be faster to first to '09[0-9]{9}' and afterwards filter for those matches that contain 62.

Answer (score 5):

You may use

```
(?<!\d)(?=\d{11}(?!\d))09\d*62\d*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wBbrKM/2)

**Details**

- `(?<!\d)` - no digit allowed immediately to the left
- `(?=\d{11}(?!\d))` - there must be 11 digits not followed with another digit immediately to the right of the current location
- `09` - a literal text
- `\d*` - 0+ digits
- `62` - a literal text
- `\d*` - 0+ digits

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/iwDTmu):

```
import re
s = '093627, 09206277, 09129627173, 097177627878328218'
print(re.findall(r'(?<!\d)(?=\d{11}(?!\d))09\d*62\d*', s))
# => ['09129627173']
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, would using a lookahead at the start make it more efficient? `(?<!\d)(?=\d{11}(?!\d))09\d*62\d*` +1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Yes, a good idea. I was actually thinking of reducing the lookrounds in the pattern, just was distracted.

Comment: As a minor length reduction, if you put the `09\d*62` part as the positive lookahead and move the `(?!\d)` negative lookahead to the end, the character-consuming portion can just be `\d{11}` and you don't need any trailing `\d*`. E.g. `(?<!\d)(?=09\d*62)\d{11}(?!\d)` for the whole thing. I'm deleting my answer since it's essentially the same as yours.